# "find -readable" finds non readable folders

Tags: linux, unix, find

```
$ find -readable
find: ‘./folder1’: Permission denied
```

Assuming `find` checks the "r" permission for directories the same way it does for files,

1. Why would `find` print the non readable folders?
2. Why would `find` even attempt to read them?
3. Why would `find` show the permission denied message?

Is the difference between a file and a folder so drastic for `find` to have such a different behavior depending on which one it is?

Comment: It's not printing the non-readable folders. It's getting an error when it tries to go into it to look for readable files in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `-readable` option is just telling `find` which files and directories to show in the results, it has no effect on the directory traversal. By default it tries to go into all directories, and reports an error when it can't access a directory.

You can use the `-prune` option to tell `find` not to try to descend into a directory that meets some criteria.

```
find -type d -not -readable -prune -o -readable -print
```

Comment: Cool. I'm studying `find`, and `-prune` didn't make sense to me, until I saw it in this picture and understood that you must use prune with a criteria. So killed two birds with one stone. Thanks.